# Giving a composite score for merged dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on a project that needs to say that a certain ID is most likely.
Let me explain using example.
I have 3 dictionaries that contain ID's and their score

Ex: d1 = {74701: 3, 90883: 2}

I assign percentage score like this,

d1_p =  {74701: 60.0, 90883: 40.0} , here the score is the (value of key in d1)/(total sum of values)

Similarly i have 2 other dictionaries

d2 = {90883: 2, 74701: 2} , d2_p = {90883.0: 50.0, 74701.0: 50.0}

d3 = {75853: 2}, d3_p = {75853: 100.0}

My task is to give a composite score for each ID from the above 3 dictionaries a decide a winner by taking the highest score. How would i mathematically assign a composite score between 0-100 for each of these ID's??

Ex: in above case 74701 needs to be the clear winner.

I tried giving average, but it fails, because I need to give more preference for the ID's that occur in multiple dictionaries.
Ex: lets say 74701 was majority in d1 and d2 with 30,40 values. then its average will be (30+40+0)/3 = 23.33 , while 75853 which occurs only once with 100% will get (100+0+0)/3 = 33.33 and it will be given as winner, which is wrong.

Hence can somone suggest a good mathematical way in python with maybe code to give such score and decide majority?

Comment: Why would you consider 33.33% for 75853 wrong? After all, it did get a 100% score in one instance - why is an ID that got a 30%, 40% and 0% score better than an ID that got 0%, 0% and 100%?

Comment: Are you perhaps creating a red herring yourself by introducing percentages of total score and are you more after a sum of normalised scores?

Comment: The reason 75853 got 100% is cause it did not have any other ID's in that dic, its score was 1 and 1/1 =  100% . As i said winner should be a ID that occured in multiple dictonaries. only when there is absolutely no intersection, then i can say 75853 is winner.

Comment: Is there a way to get all 3 dictionaries to a same scale / like normalize them and give percentages?

Comment: My feeling is that your approaching this problem the wrong way. If you are working with frequencies, you should summarize the 3 dictionaries into one with accumulated values. Why would not that work for you?

Comment: @luizbarcelos is correct, you can make a new dict adding the values of the keys in all dictionaries so they all reference the same scale.

Comment: @luizbarcelos could you give me an example? didnt quite follow what you said

Comment: Sure, I'll send as an answer so I can explain in detail, give me a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a global score from different dictionaries, since your main goal is to analyze frequency I would suggest to summarize all the data into a single dictionary, which is less error prone in general. Say I have 3 dictionaries:

```
a = {1: 2, 2: 3}
b = {2: 4, 3: 5}
c = {3: 4, 4: 9}
```

You could summarize these three dictionaries into one by summing the values for each key:

```
result = {1: 2, 2: 7, 3: 9, 4: 9}
```

That could be easily achieved by using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter(a)
result.update(Counter(b))
result.update(Counter(c))
result = dict(result)
```

Which would yield the desired summary. If you want different weights for each dictionary that could also be done in a similar fashion, the takeaway is that you should not be trying to obtain information from the dictionaries as separate entities, but instead merge them together into one statistic.

Comment: Thank you , I think this makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Think of the data in a tabular way: for each game/match/whatever, each ID gets
a certain number of points. If you care the most about overall point total for
the entire sequences of games (the entire "season", so to speak), then add up
the points to determine a winner (and then scale everything down/up to 0 to
100).

```text
      74701   90883   75853
---------------------------
1         3       2       0
2         2       2       0
3         0       0       2
Total     5       4       2
```

Alternatively, we can express those same scores in percentage terms per game.
Again, every ID must be given a value. In this case, we need to average the
percentages -- all of them, including the zeros:

```text
      74701   90883   75853
---------------------------
1        .6      .4       0
2        .5      .5       0
3         0       0     100
Avg     .37     .30     .33
```

Both approaches could make sense, depending on the context. And both also
declare 74701 to be the winner, as desired. But notice that they give different
results for 2nd and 3rd place. Such differences occur because the two systems
prioritize different things. You need to decide which approach you prefer.

Either way, the first step is to organize the data better. It seems more
convenient to have all scores or percentages for each ID, so you can do the
needed math with them: that sounds like a dict mapping IDs to lists of scores
or percentages.

```python
# Put the data into one collection.
d1 = {74701: 3, 90883: 2}
d2 = {90883: 2, 74701: 2}
d3 = {75853: 2}
raw_scores = [d1, d2, d3]

# Find all IDs.
ids = tuple(set(i for d in raw_scores for i in d))

# Total points/scores for each ID.
points = {
    i : [d.get(i, 0) for d in raw_scores]
    for i in ids
}

# If needed, use that dict to create a similar dict for percentages. Or you
# could create a dict with the same structure holding *both* point totals and
# percentages. Just depends on the approach you pick.
pcts = {}
for i, scores in points.items():
    tot = sum(scores)
    pcts[i] = [sc / tot for sc in scores]
```